# About the Generalized singular value decomposition (GSVD).

Tags: reference-request, numerical-linear-algebra

I have studied about Singular value decomposition (SVD) and had solved few numerical examples  to understand SVD. Now I am studying Generalized singular value decomposition  (GSVD). I followed [this link](http://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/Abdi-SVD2007-pretty.pdf) to grasp the concept of GSVD but I haven't been able to understand. I have failed in finding any numerical example based on GSVD.

I need help to to understand GSVD. Any numerical example based on GSVD will be very much helpful to me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gsvd.html http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn46.pdf

Comment: did those help at all?

Comment: @amzoti Unfortunately not very much. I am not able to understand properly.

Comment: I might give it a go, but this is a specialized algorithm and not much documentation out there. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti It would be a great help for me. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Amzoti Here is the link of the paper I am reading (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0096300305005643). Lemma 1.1 uses this algorithm. That is why I want to know about GSVD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several papers about the GSVD, the most useful ones (for me) were [Paige and Saunders](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0718026?journalCode=sjnaam), [Chu et al.](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0895479895287079?mobileUi=0), [Van Loan](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0713009?journalCode=sjnaam), [Kagstrom](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01934915.pdf) and for an example application see [Kempf et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.00345?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%253A+arxiv%252FQSXk+%2528ExcitingAds%2521+cs+updates+on+arXiv.org%2529) (free). A reference book is *Matrix Computations* from Golub and Van Loan.

Recently, a higher-order GSVD was developed see [Ponnapalli et al.](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0028072) and [Kempf et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.09822) (free), which works for more than two matrices.

In essence, given two matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ with equal number of columns, then the GSVD factorizes each matrix as $A_i=U_i\Sigma_i V^T$, where $U_i$ is orthogonal, $\Sigma_i\succeq 0$ diagonal and $V$, which is shared among the factorizations, invertible. In addition, $\Sigma_1^2+\Sigma_2^2=I$. In case that $A_2=I$, the GSVD gives you the SVD of $A_1$ (hence the generalized SVD).

You can quite straightforwardly try to compute it yourself, e.g. in Matlab. These are the steps:

1. Compute $S=\frac{1}{2}(A_1^TA_1(A_2^TA_2)^{-1}+A_2^TA_2(A_1^TA_1)^{-1})$
2. Compute the eigenvector matrix of $S$ s.t. $SV=V\Lambda$, with $\Lambda$ being the eigenvalues of $S$
3. Compute $B_i=A_i(V^T)^{-1}$
4. If $B_i=[b_{i,1},\dots,b_{i,n}]$, where $b_{i,j}$ denotes a column of $B_i$, then normalize each column of $B_i$ to obtain $U_i$ and set $\Sigma_i = \text{diag}(||b_{i,1}||_2,\dots,||b_{i,n}||_2)$

You should be able to obtain a numerical examples for e.g. $2\times 2$ matrices using the above yourself.

Find the details for this approach in [Ponnapalli et al.](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0028072) or [Kempf et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.09822). If you can't compute the inverse of some $A_i^TA_i$, then check the modification in [Kempf et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.09822).

Other approaches use a QR decomposition of the stacked $A_i$ and take a detour over the cosine-sine decomposition (CSD). Some algorithms might be favorable because they are numerically stable. The above one is clearly bad for ill-conditioned $A_i$ and can also be improved by using a QR decomposition of the stacked $A_i$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. This is helpful.